# retrieving tags from result of POS tagging

Tags: python, tagging

Using python how to retrieve only the tags - 'NN', 'JJ' etc from

```
('[', 'NN'), 
("u'Tradus-Under", 'NN'), 
("'", "''"), 
(',', ','), 
("u'Maintenance", 'JJ'), 
("'", "''"), 
(']', ':')
```

ie. from POS tagging result.

Comment: how we identify the tags?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those elements are in a list (I call that list `lst`):

```
import string
lst = [
    ('[', 'NN'),
    ("u'Tradus-Under", 'NN'),
    ("'", "''"),
    (',', ','),
    ("u'Maintenance", 'JJ'),
    ("'", "''"),
    (']', ':')
]

tags = []
for _,poss_tag in lst:
    if(len(poss_tag) == 2 and 
           poss_tag[0] == poss_tag[1] and 
           poss_tag[0] in string.ascii_letters):
        tags.append(poss_tag)

print(tags)
```

Output:

```
['NN', 'NN', 'JJ']
```

If you want a unique set, you could bounce it to a set and back:

```
print(list(set(tags)))
```

Output:

```
['JJ', 'NN']
```